# CSS Float Right not working on ios Tablet

Tags: ios, css, css-float

I am having some issue with float right on an iOS tablet. The css for this works on a desktop. The issue is that the elements contained within this div don't float to the extreme right. They go about 2 thirds of the way.

The body, form, and div in the master file are all width=100%

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="FloatRight" style="padding-left: 20px; width:600px;margin:0 0 0 0;" >
    <asp:TextBox ID="FeedbackNoteTB" Width="500px" Rows="5"  TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Height="100px"/><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Include In Meeting" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="IncludeInMeetingCB" Checked="true" class="big-checkbox" CssClass="big-checkbox"  /><br />

    <asp:Button CssClass="btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" runat="server" Text="Save" ID="SaveFeedbackNoteBTN" OnClick="SaveFeedbackNoteBTN_Click" />

    <br />
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MarketFeedbackQuestions" DataSourceID="MarketFeedbackQuestionsDS" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
        <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" SortExpression="Question">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer" SortExpression="Answer">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateQuestionAnswered" SortExpression="DateQuestionAnswered">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Text='<%# Bind("DateQuestionAnswered") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateQuestionAnswered") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MarketFeedbackQuestionsDS" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXXXXXXXXXX %>" SelectCommand="SELECT  MarketFeedbackAnswerID,mfq.MarketFeedbackQuestionID,Answer,CustomerID,DateQuestionAnswered,Question,[Order] FROM XXXXXXXX mfq LEFT JOIN XXXXxXXX mfa ON mfq.MarketFeedbackQuestionID = mfa.MarketFeedbackQuestionID WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND (DateQuestionAnswered > DATEADD(day,-7,GetDate()) OR DateQuestionAnswered IS NULL)" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CustomerID" QueryStringField="cid" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

The css FloatRight class is as follows.

```
.FloatRight {
  float: right;
}
```

Does anybody know how to get my div to float to the complete right?

Comment: try `margin-left:auto`.

Comment: @Xenio Gracias Will try tomorrow at work

Comment: if this doesn't work the can you please put the working code.. this will help us to work on it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try by placing !important at last of CSS property like:

```
  .FloatRight {
     float: right !important;
  }
```

If it doesn't work try to open it in Private window because the private window doesn't collect the cache

OR

You can use the media query for the specific device